# webpack vendor files failing on dependencies

Tags: javascript, webpack, vendor

I am trying to convert a existing dynamic web page, where everything from tables to high charts are inserted via js/html code, to be create by webpack.   The js, css, images have all been modified successfully and the input files are being read in via ajax to populate the web page.  The problem is the vendor js files.   I am constantly getting error messages in the console about some js file function that is not defined or is not found with the 404 message.  I have read the docs and reviewed existing posts for vendor, so it looks ok, but its just not working.

This is what I originally had in the html file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/react.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/papaparse.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modules/treemap.js"></script>
```

To get then imported into webpack I did the following:

index.htm (removed script type for js files since webpack will included them for me).

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metaDesc %>"> 
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
</head>
```

index.js (this is the main file for webpack).  Modules are for highchart and and load in by highchart.js.

```
import {readInSoftwareVersions} from "./softwareList"
import "./styles.css"
import "./vendor/js/jquery.min.1.8.2.js"
import "./vendor/js/underscore-min.js"
import "./vendor/js/react.js"
import "./vendor/js/highcharts.js"
import "./vendor/js/highcharts-more.js"
import "./vendor/js/papaparse.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/broken-axis.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/broken-axis.src.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/canvas-tools.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/canvas-tools.src.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/data.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/data.src.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/drilldown.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/drilldown.src.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/exporting.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/exporting.src.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/funnel.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/funnel.src.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/heatmap.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/heatmap.src.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/no-data-to-display.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/no-data-to-display.src.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/solid-gauge.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/solid-gauge.src.js"
import "./vendor/js/modules/treemap.js"
import './images/lessErrors.png'
import './images/moreErrors.png'
import './images/noChange.png'
/*
Read in software list and then build web page.
*/
$(document).ready(function(){
        readInSoftwareVersions(false);  // wait for json to be read in
});
```

webpack.config.js - I listed all the js files.

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    main: "./src/index.js",
    vendor: [
        "./src/vendor/js/jquery.min.1.8.2.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/underscore-min.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/react.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/highcharts.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/highcharts-more.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/papaparse.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/broken-axis.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/broken-axis.src.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/canvas-tools.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/canvas-tools.src.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/data.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/data.src.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/drilldown.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/drilldown.src.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/exporting.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/exporting.src.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/funnel.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/funnel.src.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/heatmap.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/heatmap.src.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/no-data-to-display.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/no-data-to-display.src.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/solid-gauge.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/solid-gauge.src.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/treemap.js",
        "./src/vendor/js/modules/treemap.src.js"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: "main-[contenthash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      hash: true,
      title: 'Unit Test Results',
      metaDesc: 'Display all the test results run on the select software version',
      template: './src/index.htm',
      filename: 'index.htm',
      inject: 'body'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",   // 2. Inject styles into DOM
          "css-loader",     // 1. Turns css into commonjs
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "./images/[name].[ext]",
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  }  
};
```

There are no errors on npm compile for this setup.  Now I thought web pack would handle the dependencies, but I am seeing modules/canvas-tools.js saying highcharts AddEvent is not defined, papaparse.js not found, and other errors about missing or not declared.  Basically the js dependencies are messed up.  Moving the import order around fixes one error but then some other dependency error happens because js files in module are calling each other.

So what am I doing wrong?  Do I need some plugin for vendors?  Currently I dumped the vendor logic and inserted the script type lines back into index.htm so it runs, but the point was to bundle the js files together using webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually creating a vendor bundle from an entry point, you should create a so called `cacheGroup` for which you define a test. Here's some example code from the docs, adjusted to your situation:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  entry: {
    main: "./src/index.js"
  },
  output: {
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
       cacheGroups: {
         vendor: {
           test: /[\\/]vendor[\\/]/,
           name: 'vendors',
           chunks: 'all',
         },
       },
     },
    },
  ...
  };
```

This will add all imports from the `vendor` directory to a chunk called `vendors`. You can see the full example [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/#extracting-boilerplate).

Comment: I made the changes to module.exports, remove the script type from index to let webpack handle the js files, remove the js imports from index.js, and restored the vendor directory.  The error was  jquery was no found.  I then restored the imports for all js files in index.js and ran again.  It failed again with the this error:

Comment: canvas-tools.js:130 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
    at eval (canvas-tools.js:130:135)
    at eval (canvas-tools.js:133:421)
    at Object../src/vendor/js/modules/canvas-tools.js (main-14dd8175e56f518e4ad4.js?f46f24eb905b797eb762:67:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (main-377cee45cb0a26f17386.js?f46f24eb905b797eb762:213:42)
    at eval (index.js:23:93)
    at Module../src/index.js (main-377cee45cb0a26f17386.js?f46f24eb905b797eb762:19:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (main-377cee45cb0a26f17386.js?f46f24eb905b797eb762:213:42)

Comment: 135 offset is {p.prototype} which I have no idea that prototype is referring to, but I assume something is not imported in the right order.

Comment: @JohnK you would certainly need to import the modules you want to use for webpack to pick them up. You could try to move the related import to the bottom and continue this way until you find a configuration that works.